# How to implement a stack of game states in C++

Tags: c++, class, stack

I'm new to C++ and as a college proyect we are building a 2D platformer, I recently read that it's a good idea to have a stack of gamestates instead of a single global variable with the game state (which is what I have now) but I'm not sure how to do it.

Currently this is my implementation:

```
class GameState
{
    public:
        virtual ~GameState(){};
        virtual void handle_events() = 0;
        virtual void logic() = 0;
        virtual void render() = 0;
};

class Menu : public GameState
{
    public:
        Menu();
        ~Menu();
        void handle_events();
        void logic();
        void render();
};
```

Then I have a global variable of type GameState:

GameState *currentState = NULL;

And in my Main I define the currentState and call it's methods:

```
int main(){
    currentState = new Menu();
    currentState.handle_events();
}
```

How can I implement a stack or something similar to go from that to something like this:

```
int main(){
    statesStack.push(new Menu());
    statesStack.getTop().handle_events();
}
```

Comment: The STL includes `std::stack` see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack

Comment: Note that you don't particularly need `std::stack` here. You can push and pop perfectly well using normal containers (e.g., `vector`, `list`, or `deque`).

Comment: You mean you need a stack of *objects* or *instances*, not *classes*.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's not to say that you can't implement

```
std::stack<GameState *>
```

and still write a program that doesn't leak - it just puts the onus on you to do the memory management.

If you want to make life easier you can implement a stack of shared_ptr (using a reference counted smart pointer to track the objects lifetime and automatically call the destructor when the object is no longer required).

```
std::stack<shared_ptr<GameState>> mystack;

mystack.push_back(shared_ptr<GameState>(new GameState()));
```

Comment: thanks I think this is what I want, I couldn't run it though I tried including <stack> <memory> and <tr1/memory> but I keep getting "shared_ptr was not declared in this scope". I'll keep googling for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a `std::stack<GameState *>`.

Comment: ... and cry because there is no garbage collection?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: You could cry; more usefully, you could use a smart pointer, or you could be slightly careful when you pop.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin You could cry because C++03 has no suitable smart pointer, right.